Read real number as datetime object when creating an instance in Python class using SQLAlchemy
I have a datetime field in sqlite db which is stored as a UNIX timestamp.
I want to read the same as a datetime object when creating the instances of the records. The code I am using is as such:
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Data(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Data'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    action_datetime = Column('Time & Date', Float)

    def __init__(self, 
                id: int, 
                action_datetime: float):
        
        self.id = id
        self.action_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(action_datetime)

However, the fields are being read as unix timestamps and not datetime objects.
Ideally the instances should be stored as Data(id, datetime obj).

You can subclass TypeDecorator to implement the desired behaviour. This example is based on the MyEpochType from the linked documentation section. I have assumed you want to store the data as UTC, but you might wish to use a different timezone, or none at all.
import datetime

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import types


class MyTimestamp(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.FLOAT

    cache_ok = True

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        """Convert datetime to timestamp."""
        return value.timestamp()

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        """Convert timestamp to datetime."""
        # Consider whether you want to handle timezones
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(value, tz=datetime.UTC)

    def coerce_compared_value(self, op, value):
        if isinstance(value, float):
            return types.FLOAT
        return self

This script demonstrates that it works as expected:
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)

# Use the new "type" in the column definition
tbl = sa.Table('t', sa.MetaData(), sa.Column('c', MyTimestamp))

tbl.create(engine)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert().values(c=datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.UTC)))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    # Retrieve a Python value
    res = conn.execute(sa.select(tbl))
    print(list(res.mappings()))
    # [{'c': datetime.datetime(2024, 8, 30, 11, 2, 45, 354411, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}]

    # Retrieve the "raw" value
    res = conn.execute(sa.text("""SELECT * FROM t"""))
    print(list(res.mappings()))
    # [{'c': 1725015765.354411}]

Usage with the ORM is as you would expect:
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    action_datetime = sa.Column(MyTimestamp)

with Session(engine) as s:
    my_model = MyModel(action_datetime=datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.UTC))
    s.add(my_model)
    s.commit()

